# I want to make part of our website content in virtual reality

Tags: aframe

I want to make part of our website content in virtual reality.
For example, small games
I can't figure it out yet. It's better to do it as an application for different headsets stores.
But it's much easier to add the VR button to the site itself.
How will this industry develop? Are there developers of WebVR sites? Will all devices open VR versions of sites?

Thank you .

Comment: Hi Alex Shavel. Welcome! Your question is very broad. Could I recommend you narrowing down your question to something more specific. This will aid in getting answers to what you're looking for.

Comment: I recommend reading through A-Frame docs https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/ some of your questions are answered there

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1{
 font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="groundTexture" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/a-painter/images/floor.jpg">
  </a-assets>

  <a-cylinder id="ground" src="#groundTexture" radius="32" height="0.1"></a-cylinder>
</a-scene>
```